# borders and content missing, after LaTeX convert to word

Tags: border, missing

Here is the code !

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
截面   & 边跨跨中$M_1$ & 离端第二支座$M_B$ & \makecell[c]{离端第二跨跨中及\\ 中间跨跨中$M_2(M_3)$} & 中间支座$M_c$ \\ \hline
计算跨度$l_0/m$ & 2.07   & 2.05     & 2.05            & 2.05   \\ \hline
弯矩系数$\alpha_mp$ & $\frac{1}{11}$   & $-\frac{1}{11}$     & $ \frac{1}{16}$            & $ -\frac{1}{14}$   \\ \hline
$M=\alpha_mp(g+q)l_0^2/kN\cdot m$   & 5.30   & -5.20     & 3.58           & -4.09  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is the LaTeX pic.
[image]

This is the Word pic.
[image]

Word lost some text and borders, and I use the pandoc to convert, Please someone Help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and which font-related packages, if any, you employ. And, how or where is `\makecell` defined?

Comment: It may be better to ask this question at the pandoc mailing list.

Comment: I will try to use font packages, the ```\makecell``` is used to line break, and I defined it in the beginning, document class ```\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}```

Comment: OK!, I find a not perfect way, convert to pdf, use word to open pdf, save as docx.